# Changing background in jQuery Nice form

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used nice form from this site http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jnice/. I have to change the background image of the List/menu to another image on focus only. How can i do this?

Comment: could you tell us more about what you are trying to do? Which background image are you trying to change? which List/menu are you referring to?

Comment: I mean that the background image of "Please Choose". Now it has the white background with grey stroke and greenish arrows. I want to change them on click the List/menu

Answer (score 1):

You only need to override the original style from jNice.css

Update the background-image in below style:

```
.jNiceSelectWrapper .jNiceSelectOpen {
    background: url("http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jnice/elements/select_right.gif") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 21px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Write :hover style as per your need. because, I didn't get much clear problem here.

Some code in more detail for onHover effect as below:

```
$(".YourClass").hover(
  function(){
  $(this).css('background-image','newImagePath.jpg');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).css('background-image','oldImagePath.jpg');
  }  
 );
```

Comment: Thanks.If i click the list/menu the background image has changed as you specified. but the the issue is if i leave mouse click the changed background image retained to it's older image. What can i do?